# Updating database in php

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query i am writing for updating the data.

```
 $sql=makeSQL($myVals,$fieldsu,
        "update users set", 
        "where id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["PID"])."'");
```

But i am getting an error as

```
update users set'Amol','Kulkarni','amol@e10.in','amol','9870004268')Error Save [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Amol','Kulkarni','amol@e10.in','amol','9870004268')' at line 1]
```

Suggest me on this....

Comment: What is makeSQL? And, yes it's a syntax error because what you wrote is not SQL.

Comment: Your `makeSQL` function is generating an incorrect SQL query.

Comment: There is no space after set and as juergen has stated, you don't tell it which columns to set. Without the space it reads `setwhere`.

Comment: This is not correct Sql query,

Comment: UPDATE tableName SET fieldname=newvalue WHERE condition this is the syntax

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify which columns you want to set like this

```
update your_table set col1 = 'a', col2 = 'b' where id = 3
```

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please fix that problem first. See [best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: On what basis is this vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: Directly using input parameter from the web.

Comment: This no direct, since variable is passed through `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql=makeSQL("update users set colname1=$myVals, cloname2=$fields
        where id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["PID"])."'");
```

Notice the `SET` clause in the statement along with the values that need to be set.

Comment: i am trying this one but again i am getting an error as Error Save [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''u')' at line 1]

Comment: Even as amended, you need to worry about converting `$myVals` and `$fields` into strings if the columns are strings, and worry about [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) even if they're not.  The SQL syntax is more nearly well-formed, though.